# Identify the last occurrence of a column value for each customer and select only those rows that are between that and last

Tags: sql

| ID | Event | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 100 |
| 1 | B | 105 |
| 1 | C | 115 |
| 1 | A | 160 |
| 1 | B | 100 |
| 1 | C | 180 |
| 1 | A | 100 |
| 1 | D | 250 |
| 2 | A | 100 |
| 2 | B | 105 |
| 2 | C | 115 |
| 2 | A | 160 |
| 2 | R | 100 |
| 3 | B | 180 |
| 3 | C | 100 |
| 3 | D | 250 |
| 4 | A | 180 |
| 4 | C | 100 |
| 4 | D | 250 |
| 4 | B | 180 |
| 4 | C | 100 |
| 4 | Y | 250 |

I would like to start with the last occurrence of C in Event field for each ID and filter out all the rows before the last occurrence of C (for each ID).

So, the desired SQL query will yield the following result:

[image]

I used ROW_NUMBER() window function with a Where clause to capture only the rows where the last C occurred but cannot proceed from here even after much trying.  Is it possible?

[The color-coded one should be helpful.]
[image]

Comment: Just how are you defining "last" and "before"? why is 180 the last value for C for ID 1 (and it's not because that's how you've shown it)

Comment: Was B not included in the desired query results on purpose? I would also say without some sort of indicator within the original coding you are going to be pressed to get a correct "last" result as their is no way other than strictly the ordering of the rows themselves which is truly the final event. Usually you would want some sort of indicator or date to associate with this type of data structure.

Comment: To make is easier, I added a Date column.
The last C is the C corresponding to the max date of any C within a specific ID. Shown in dark green.
To give you more context, each ID can go through the cycle of (A...Z) multiple times. A...Z has a natural order where A > B > C etc but I do not think orderless makes it structurally different.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The *date* column is the missing piece, given that you can use it in a correlated subquery for filtering required rows:

```
select * 
from t
where date >= (
  select Max(date) 
  from t t2 
  where t2.event='C' and t2.id = t.id
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked almost perfectly. The only issue is some unwanted rows (in my original set) get included where the max date is same. Will appreciate your feedback on this but the solution so far is good enough and I will try to build on this.

Comment: When tailored your code to my dataset, it returned 1.4 million rows. I was not sure if running a correlated subquery would be a good idea - so ran it on a subset of my data. I am ok with the 7-10 seconds that the code execution takes.

Question: Do you have a ready way to copy-paste example/sample table from here to a SQL tool (something like inserting data from clipboard)? Asking as it can be cumbersome to create table from example data when the INSERT code is absent.

THANKS!

Comment: If I am not wrong, I believe I was able to get rid of the unwanted rows that happend to have the same max date.
Here is what I did - I inserted a row_number across the data set and used that instead of using the date column.